# Plot combinations in R

Tags: r

I have seen the plot below but don't know what it is called and haven't been able to find the right search terms. The input data would be a dataset with items that can be classified as members of groups A, B, and/or C. The columns represent the number of items that fall into each of the 5 combinations of group memberships that exist in the data set, i.e., there are 50 items that belong to groups A, B and C; 32 that belong to A and B but not C; etc. What is this type of plot called?
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **upset plot**, and it's showing how many elements are shared among different sets, e.g. there are 50 elements present in all groups. This plot is useful if you have ca. >4 sets so a Venn diagram would be too messy.
You can use R packages [UpSetR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UpSetR/vignettes/basic.usage.html) or [ggupset](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggupset/readme/README.html) to plot them.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an opinion on which package better/easier? It appears `UpSetR` is the original on which `ggupset` is based. But `ggupset` uses `ggplot2` syntax, which is nice.

Comment: choose it whether you want to use ggplot grammar or not